# How do I resize a Label's width?

Tags: label, size, width, gtk3, pygobject

I've been trying to resize a label's width for a while, but it seems IMPOSSIBLE, or at least incomprehensible for me...

I'll explain my situation with images for the sake of clarity.

[image]

This is how the Window looks with a "Normal" Label...

[image]

This is how the Window looks with a ridiculously large text...

[image]

Now, THIS IS how I want it to look when text is ridiculously large

See?

Here's the example code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import gi
import signal
import hashlib
import random
gi.require_version("Gtk", "3.0")
from gi.repository import Gtk, Pango

class Test(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        def center(a):
            a.props.valign = Gtk.Align.CENTER
            a.props.halign = Gtk.Align.CENTER
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="Test")
        self.set_position(Gtk.WindowPosition.CENTER)
        self.set_border_width(10)
        self.set_resizable(False)
        self.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)

        Box = Gtk.Box(orientation=Gtk.Orientation.HORIZONTAL, spacing=10)
        Button = Gtk.Button("Change Label")
        Label = Gtk.Label()

        Test = "I'm a Label, Yay!"

        center(Box)
        center(Label)
        center(Button)

        Label.set_markup('<span><big>%s</big></span>' % Test)
        Label.set_ellipsize(Pango.EllipsizeMode.END)
        Label.set_justify(Gtk.Justification.LEFT)

        self.add(Box)

        Box.add(Label)
        Box.add(Button)

        #UNKNOWN/FORBIDDEN/DEPRECIATED/INCOMPREHENSIBLE MAGIC!
            #Uncomment only one or both, and watch it's magic!

        #self.set_resizable(True)
        #Box.set_resize_mode(Gtk.ResizeMode.QUEUE)

        def change_label(self):
            Label.set_markup('<span><big>%s</big></span>' % str(hashlib.sha384(str(random.random())).hexdigest()))

        Button.connect("clicked", change_label)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainWindow = Test()
    MainWindow.show_all()
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_DFL)
    Gtk.main()
```

Please note that the Window IS NOT resizable.

If you uncomment one or both of the "Magic" section, you'll see how the Window changes it's behaviour!

BUT

There are two disadvantages while using each one of this approaches:

- If you uncomment `#self.set_resizable(True)` WINDOW WILL BECOME RESIZABLE AGAIN, which I don't want it to happen
- `#Box.set_resize_mode(Gtk.ResizeMode.QUEUE)` appears to be the "Perfect" solution, but while it does what I want, it seems it has been "Depreciated" in recent versions of Gtk.

Moreover, in some other Window Managers & Themes, It causes some disruptions on Window's dimentions when you change the Label's String a lot of times.

Do you have any suggestions on this?

I'm totally fed up with this. I've been trying for weeks, with no result :c

Maybe there's a way to emulate the behaviour when Window is resizable, while NOT showing Resize Grips & Maximize Button?

Or what's the newer method to do `set_resize_mode(Gtk.ResizeMode.QUEUE)` ?

PD: `Label.set_max_width_chars()` isn't what I'm  searching for

Comment: Can you explain why `set_max_width_chars()` is not an option?

Comment: Because that limits words to the specified lenght that you requested. That would work in some cases, BUT let's imagine that you might want to add German translations. In English, for example, you could set Label's Text to "awesome" and `Label.set_max_width_chars(7). In German, Label's text would be "Ehrfurcht gebietend" (At least Google Translator said that).

Comment: I get the point. Could you use the string length to set the width value so that it matches the initial text and then if the label is changed the width stays the same.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is something like telling the Label, Or Label's Parent, Or the Window itself to display as much text as possible within the actual width. I wouldn't like to "Restrict" Label's width manually using `Label.set_max_width_chars()`. I need it to be something like: "Hey, sorry, I displayed all the Text I could, it's not my fault"

I don't want it to depend on a manually stated value, only on the actual Window's width, which could vary.

Why don't you try my Example Code to more-or-less see what I'm trying to achieve?

Comment: I found something interesting: https://developer.gnome.org/pygtk/stable/class-gtkwidget.html#method-gtkwidget--queue-resize

If I understand correctly, It says that Gtk.Label AUTOMATICALLY calls `queue_resize()` whenever it detects that it's own label has changed

At this point, i'm thinking in:

* Is there a way to "Deactivate" this behaviour, so Gtk.Label won't auto-resize itself. Maybe supressing calls to `queue.resize`

Maybe we should create a custom `Gtk.Label` that doesn't call `queue.resize`?

Comment: * Or, maybe there's a way to "Clear" resizing queue, so once Gtk.Label has called a resizing, it inmmediatly gets cleared, as if no call had been made?

* What about overriding `queue.resize`? How could we do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After hours of research and experimenting, I found another great way to accomplish this task. In my opinion, this is the best way to do it, unless it may be a little limited, but it allows you to do more that the first method and with less code.

Here's what I've done:

- From 1° method, I removed the "hackish" code
- Then, I added a "Mini-Box" object, which is a Gtk.ButtonBox (A special  kind of box...) and set it as "Homogeneous"
- Afterwards, I removed the "Button" object from "Box" and added both "Label" & "Button" objects to the "Mini-Box"
- Not to mention that I had to add "Mini-Box" to "Box" too...

Done!

Here's the example code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python2

# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import gi
import signal
import hashlib
import random
import time
gi.require_version("Gtk", "3.0")
from gi.repository import Gtk, Pango

class TestWindow(Gtk.Window):

    def __init__(self):

        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="Test")
        self.set_position(Gtk.WindowPosition.CENTER)
        self.set_border_width(10)
        self.set_resizable(False)
        self.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)

        ##Declare Objects

        #Boxes
        Box = Gtk.Box(orientation=Gtk.Orientation.HORIZONTAL, spacing=10)
        Mini_Box = Gtk.ButtonBox(orientation=Gtk.Orientation.HORIZONTAL, spacing=10, homogeneous=True)

        #Buttons
        Button = Gtk.Button.new_with_mnemonic("_Randomize Label")

        #Labels
        Label = Gtk.Label()

        #Variables & Misc
        Test = "I'm a Label, Yay!" #Label's width should NOT be larger than the Button's size to be displayed entirely, though...

        ##Change Objects Properties

        #Alignments
        self.center(Box)

        #Labels
        Label.set_markup('<span><big>%s</big></span>' % Test)
        Label.set_ellipsize(Pango.EllipsizeMode.END)
        Label.set_justify(Gtk.Justification.LEFT)

        ##Packaging

        #Boxes
        self.add(Box)

        Box.add(Mini_Box)
        Mini_Box.add(Label)
        Mini_Box.add(Button)

        def change_label(self):
            Label.set_markup('<span><big>%s</big></span>' % str(hashlib.sha384(str(random.random())).hexdigest()).rstrip())

        Button.connect("clicked", change_label)

    def center(self, object):
        object.props.valign = Gtk.Align.CENTER
        object.props.halign = Gtk.Align.CENTER

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainWindow = TestWindow()
    MainWindow.show_all()
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_DFL)
    Gtk.main()
```

**Won't post new screenshots, because the result is the same as above...**

Comment: I think this will be my "Definitive" answer to this topic. Upvote it so people will read this first

Answer (score 2):

You may want to read about frame clock in Gtk 3.12. Here is a good [article](https://blogs.gnome.org/alexl/2013/11/04/the-modern-gtk-drawing-model/).
The new method to use in order to queue a resize is Gtk.Widget.queue_resize()

> If some state changes that causes the size of your widget to change you call gtk_widget_queue_resize() which will request a layout phase and mark your widget as needing relayout.

I believe the modified sample code below does what you want. The trick consist in having sub-boxes to enclose the `Gtk.Label` and `Gtk.Button`. You then set `max_width_chars` to `1`, `ellipsize` to `END`, `hexpand` to `True` and `halign` to `FILL` on the label.

```
import signal
import hashlib
import random
gi.require_version("Gtk", "3.0")
from gi.repository import Gtk, Pango

class Test(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="Test")
        self.set_size_request(250,-1)
        self.set_position(Gtk.WindowPosition.CENTER)
        self.set_border_width(10)
        self.set_resizable(False)
        self.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)

        Box = Gtk.Box(orientation=Gtk.Orientation.HORIZONTAL, spacing=10)
        Sub_box_left = Gtk.Box(orientation=Gtk.Orientation.HORIZONTAL)
        Sub_box_right = Gtk.Box(orientation=Gtk.Orientation.HORIZONTAL)
        Button = Gtk.Button("Change Label")
        Label = Gtk.Label()

        Test = "I'm a Label, Yay!"

        Label.set_markup('<span><big>%s</big></span>' % Test)
        Label.set_max_width_chars(1)
        Label.set_ellipsize(Pango.EllipsizeMode.END)
        Label.set_hexpand(True)
        Label.props.halign = Gtk.Align.FILL
        Label.set_justify(Gtk.Justification.LEFT)

        self.add(Box)

        Sub_box_left.add(Label)
        Sub_box_right.add(Button)

        Box.add(Sub_box_left)
        Box.add(Sub_box_right)

        def change_label(self):
            Label.set_markup('<span><big>%s</big></span>'%str(hashlib.sha384(str(random.random())).hexdigest()))

        Button.connect("clicked", change_label)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainWindow = Test()
    MainWindow.show_all()
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_DFL)
    Gtk.main()
```

Comment: I edited my answer according to the discussion above. I hope this is what you want to achieve.

Comment: Indeed, It was a good approach. I decided to see analize both codes, and found that you can actually modify even less "My" code to achieve what yours is able to.

Comment: For example:

* If you add `Label.set_max_width_chars(1)`, `Label.set_hexpand(True)`, `self.set_size_request(250,-1)` & delete `center(Box)`, `center(Label)`, `center(Button)` you'll achieve the same as if you were using "your" code

Moreover, there's another way to set `Label.set_hexpand(True)`. You'll need to properly package the Label inside the Box using `Box.pack_start(Label, True, True, 0)`. That way, you're telling the Box to let the Label expand and fill into the available space.

That way, you won't need `Label.set_hexpand(True)` and `Label.props.valign = Gtk.Align.CENTER`

Comment: Glad it finally worked. The code I have posted is just an illustration of the idea. You can tweak it to your taste.

Comment: Also the extra boxes shouldn't be necessary aymore...

The disadvantage here would be: How could we "center" the label?

`center(Label)` will override `Label.set_hexpand(True)` or `Box.pack_start(Label, True, True, 0)`

I also forgot to mention that, despite all the effort, event if you add & delete all those lines of code, IF you delete `self.set_size_request(250,-1)` everything's lost.

And that's almost the same as if you add `Label.set_max_width_chars(x)` to the 1° code, because ANYWAYS you're manually setting a fixed size to a container, which I'm trying to avoid

Comment: LOL. Maybe I need to be faster when posting comments, xD. That was supposed to go before your `Glad it finally worked. The code I have posted is just an illustration of the idea. You can tweak it to your taste` comment

Comment: Im thinking on a hackish way to dynamically `set_size_request`... While I try that, what do you think of the above?

Comment: I believe you need to keep the sub-boxes as it is the widget that say to the label to expand as much as it can as far as I understand it. I may be wrong. I don't think the set size request is a big problem. Most applications have a size that make them comfortable to use. I don't know what you are developing but you should have an idea of what will make the end user happy!

Comment: Yep, I'll keep trying, hehe. In fact, yes, this is "related" to a proyect of mine, but this is essentialy a matter that was curious to me.

The real application is fine, don't worry :D

Thanks for all your help, and see my own answer, maybe you'll be able to improve it.

Do you know someone who can help me improving my answer? Invite him, :), it would be awesome

Answer (score 0):

Well, after a little thinking, i found a "hackish" way to achieve what I was trying to.

I'll try to explain it with words, and afterward I'l, post the "Final" code, but I'm convinced it could be optimized, or at least that's what I'm hoping :)

What I did, was to take both codes, (Original & Modified version by Jacques Gaudin), analyze them and create a less complicated version.

Then I realized that Jacques Gaudin's modifications made the Window `set_size_request` dependant from developer as it neeeded width and height.

As a "workaround" I decided to do the following:

- Clean the code
- Let the Window "appear" without restrictions, so it could calculate the exact width and height required for it to display correctly, and inmmediatly hide the window to avoid user from pressing the "Randomize Button" too early.
- Once the Window has hid itself, request it the exact values (Width & Height)
- After it gathered those values, while the Window is still hidden, re-declare the `MainWindow` object, but this time changing its arguments from `(None, None)` to the previously gathered values: `(Width, Height)`
- Next, the Window would need to recalculate some internal values as a consequence from changing its arguments
- Finally, once the Window has finished re-calculating values, it displays itself again, BUT this time with the desired Width & Height to display propely AND even if for some reason the Label grows, the Window will stay with the same size.

I know this isn't the "best" answer, but at least it works.

Unfortunately, there are a few questions remaining:

- How could we "center" the label?
- If this method is used in slow machines, would it be possible that window will be slow when hiding, causing some kind of bug/glitch if the user presses the "Randomize" button yoo early?
- What about dynamic text translations? Would they be even possible without needing to "restart" the Window? (Well, that wouldn't be a big problem, but still curious to think about...)
- **IS THERE ANY BETTER WAY TO ACHIEVE THIS?** (The most important question :c)

Here's the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python2

# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import gi
import signal
import hashlib
import random
gi.require_version("Gtk", "3.0")
from gi.repository import Gtk, Pango

class TestWindow(Gtk.Window):
    
    def __init__(self, width, height):
        
        if width is None:
            width = -1
            
        if height is None:
            height = -1
            
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="Test")
        self.set_position(Gtk.WindowPosition.CENTER)
        self.set_border_width(10)
        self.set_resizable(False)
        self.set_size_request(width, height)
        self.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)
        
        ##Declare Objects
        
        #Boxes
        Box = Gtk.Box(orientation=Gtk.Orientation.HORIZONTAL, spacing=10)
        
        #Buttons
        Button = Gtk.Button.new_with_mnemonic("Randomize Label")
        
        #Labels
        Label = Gtk.Label()
        
        #Variables & Misc
        Test = "I'm a Label, Yay!" #You can change me for a bigger label if you want
        
        ##Change Objects Properties
        
        #Alignments (Could break things...)
        #self.center(Box)
        #self.center(Label)
        #self.center(Button)
        
        #Labels
        Label.set_markup('<span><big>%s</big></span>' % Test)
        Label.set_ellipsize(Pango.EllipsizeMode.END)
        
        if width is not -1:
            Label.set_max_width_chars(1)
            
        Label.set_justify(Gtk.Justification.FILL)
        
        ##Packaging
        
        #Boxes
        self.add(Box)
        
        Box.pack_start(Label, True, True, 0)
        Box.add(Button)
        
        def change_label(self):
            Label.set_markup('<span><big>%s</big></span>' % str(hashlib.sha384(str(random.random())).hexdigest()))
            
        Button.connect("clicked", change_label)
            
    def center(self, object):
        object.props.valign = Gtk.Align.CENTER
        object.props.halign = Gtk.Align.CENTER
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainWindow = TestWindow(None, None)
    MainWindow.show_all()
    MainWindow.hide()
    Width, Height = MainWindow.get_size()
    MainWindow = TestWindow(Width, Height)
    MainWindow.show_all()
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_DFL)
    Gtk.main()
```

Here are some screenshots:

[image]

This is "Before" pressing the button...

[image]

This is "After" pressing the button...